# Get Date set in DatePickerDialog when Neutral button is clicked

Tags: android

I am attempting to have my `DatePickerDialog` open up a `TimePickerDialog` when the Neutral button is pressed, however, it seems I have hit a dead end with trying to find an answer.

- First, I thought about putting in an `OnClick` listener, but then how do I get the date?
- Second, if I use the `onDateSet` in `datePickerDialog`, how do I check if the Neutral button has been pressed?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class DatePickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{
int position;

@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public DatePickerDialogFragment(int position) {
    this.position = position;
}
public DatePickerDialogFragment() {
    this(-1);
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    datePickerDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    datePickerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Set Time", //What do I do here?);
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
    if (position != -1)
    new RecyclerAdapter(getActivity()).notifyItemChanged(position);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    Log.d("We have liftoff!", "DPD Listener called!");
    Log.d("onDateSet method", "Date set for: "+ dayOfMonth + "/" + monthOfYear + "/" + year);

    if (position == -1) {
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setAlarm(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        // Call method from other activity
    }
    else {
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setAlarm(position, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I should have thought of this before, but all I did was use the `datePickerDialog.getDatePicker.getWhatever` to get my values from the DatePicker, then pass it. I am officially an idiot.